# Is there a standard value for burn account?

Tags: spl-token, spl-token-program

From the solana docs it seems that there is no specific burn account (see [link](https://spl.solana.com/token#burning)). Is there a conventional value that people use to signify a burn? The context here is marking a token transfer as a burn through the destination account.

Comment: Are you trying to do this programmatically or via a wallet?

Comment: This is purely for labeling purposes when parsing a txn. Nothing to do with running a contract or anything.

Answer (score 4):

No.  Tokens should be burnt by issuing the [`Burn` instruction](https://spl.solana.com/token#burning) declared by the SPL Token program.

Actual native (not wrapped!) lamports (SOL) can be sent to [the incinerator](https://explorer.solana.com/address/1nc1nerator11111111111111111111111111111111).  Sending *any* other asset to this address is the wrong thing to do 100% of the time.  It wastes the rent-exempt reserve balance and litters the accounts set with unwanted and now uncontrollable accounts